# About config.xml in Magento

Tags: magento

Hello I try to add a custom Discount to Order Total and I found a tutorial

http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-discount-total-magento

But I don't understand

```
<global>
     <sales>
        <quote>
            <totals>
                <discount>
                    <class>Ikantam_BasicLoyalty_Model_ Discount</class>
                    <after>subtotal</after>
                </ discount >
            </totals>
        </quote>

        <order_invoice>
            <totals>
                <discount >
                    <class>Ikantam_BasicLoyalty_Model_ Invoice </class>
                    <after>subtotal</after>
                </discount >
            </totals>
        </order_invoice>

        <order_creditmemo>
            <totals>
                <discount >
                    <class>Ikantam_BasicLoyalty_Model_Creditmemo</class>
                    <after>subtotal</after>
                </discount >
            </totals>
        </order_creditmemo>
   </sales>
```

What does it mean ?

Comment: I don't understand <sales> ... </sales>

Answer (score 0):

In this example, they are creating a module with namespace=Ikantum and modulename=BasicLoyalty.  So the config.xml would be saved in /app/code/local/Ikantum/BasicLoyalty/etc

For some reason, there are extra spaces in some of those discount tags which I would remove.